# Save prepared statement result into decimal variable

Tags: mysql

As far as I understood from reading other answers, we can't use local variables in prepared statements. Since user variables have no type, how can we store statement's result in decimal?

The following code would convert the result to integer.

```
set @mypenetration = null;
set @sql = 'select max(penetration) into ? from (select penetration from fssector2 where penetration > 0 order by penetration asc LIMIT ? ) as MyResult ;';
prepare stm1 from @sql;
execute stm1 using @myPenetration, @a;
SELECT @mypenetration;
```

How could I get decimal out of it ?

Comment: `Parameter markers can be used only where data values should appear, not for SQL keywords, identifiers, and so forth.` - [13.5.1 PREPARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/prepare.html).

Comment: Can you post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE fssector2`?.

Comment: Check: [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/774611/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use user-defined variable directly in the query:

```
set @mypenetration = null;
set @sql = 'select CONVERT(max(penetration), DECIMAL(10,2)) into @mypenetration from (select penetration from fssector2 where penetration > 0 order by penetration asc LIMIT ? ) as MyResult ;';
prepare stm1 from @sql;
execute stm1 using @a;
SELECT @mypenetration;
```

You may also use `CONVERT()` to convert the value into DECIMAL(10,2), for example.

Comment: `@mypenetration` is a [9.4 User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html), isn't a [13.6.4.1 Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html).

Comment: @wchiquito, point taken. I fixed the answer to clarify that _user-defined_ variables can be used in prepared statements. In this case `CONVERT()` can be used to specify the type.

Comment: Thank you, +1. [CONVERT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) is really necessary?

Comment: Yes, `CONVERT()` is what defines the type in this case. Otherwise `SELECT` will return column results using the same type as `MAX(penetration)`, which in turns returns same type as `penetration`.

Comment: `penetration` column is integer?

Comment: @wchiquito, I assume it to be non-decimal since If it'd be `DECIMAL` to begin with, the conversion wouldn't be needed.